# Django: Database Model For Prize Structure

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to go about structuring a model for a contest's payout/prize structure, an example is below

1st: $50000
2nd: $10000
3rd-10th: $1000
10th-70th: $500
70th-150th: $25
150th-400th: $1

My first thought was to design it like this:

```
class Prize(models.Model):
    place=models.IntegerField()
    prize=models.IntegerField()
```

The issue for me is that once you get to the lower tier, you begin having multiple entries that are repetitive.  So from 150th-400th I would have 250 of the same entries.  I'm wondering if there is a smarter way to go about this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, never use integers to store prices. Always try to use decimal field. If you have never tried it, there is a thing to notice. You have to supply max_digits and decimal_places. For example:

```
prize = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

So you can only use 8 digits (not 10) with 2 decimal places.

In order to answer your question. Add **from range** and **to range**.
Then also in meta add unique_together, so you will not have duplicates for  the same ranges with the same prize.

Comment: When those are only integers - there is no problem, but when designing architecture, you should never predict that you will never use prizes with decimal field. Let's say the prize would be 499.99. In that case you also should not use float field, because "roundings" are not working as expected. So you always should use decimal fields.

Comment: Even if that were so , I reallly don't see why you need to use decimals instead of floats

Comment: Always use DecimalField for money. Even simple operations (addition, subtraction) are not immune to float rounding issues: 

>>> 10.50 - 0.20
10.300000000000001

>>> Decimal('10.50') - Decimal('0.20')
Decimal('10.30')

Comment: May I point out that the standard pratice specially with online payment gateways etc is to use the so called 'minor currency' format. Where everything is actuallly stored as an integer. Ie you store cents instead of dollars.